# Does CloudFoundry java buildpack support @Resource anotation?

Tags: cloud-foundry

Does CloudFoundry java buildpack support @Resource anotation?

If I deploy a Java EE war file containing following:
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html

Can javax.sql.DataSource be automatically injected ?

Thanks,
Guoping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you push a WAR file to Cloud Foundry, the Java buildpack will deploy that using the latest supported version of Apache Tomcat.  You can use any supported features of Apache Tomcat.

Hope that helps!